# Using LINQ, from a List<Object>, How to retrieve a list that contains entries repeated more than once and their values

Tags: list, duplicates

Using LINQ, from a List, retrieve a list that contains entries repeated more than once and their values.

I have list of objects as below : var lstNames = new List { }; 
where Input is class with 10 properties.

I would like to filter and remove the duplicates ones.

Comment: Your list of objects is empty, so there are no duplicates ;)